# Node-Red Having Issues Parsing Payload Data

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have node red successfully running and am feeding it from a couple of different PLC systems,

I have a payload like this.

```
{"d":779,"dt":3,"ts":"2018-04-05T19:54:12.930758Z","q":18}
```

The fields would break down to.

```
d=779  dt=3  ts=2018-04-05T19:54:12.930758Z  q=18
```

I have been attempting to parse the string and break it down (even just one field "d").
I have been trying to write a function to parse the data using combinations of splice and split.

Does anyone have a simple solution to this?  Am I even using the correct node process?

I know this is completely not working but it was an attempt the read the first field.  It is not padded and therefore needs to start where the colon is and end with the comma.

```
var str = msg.payload;
var th = str.slice(5,-1); 
th = th.split(",");
msg.payload[0] = parseFloat(th[0]);
return [ msg.payload[0]];
```

Have a source MQTT Buffer of:

[123,34,100,34,58,51,48,54,56,44,34,100,116,34,58,50,44,34,116,115,34,58,34,50,48,49,56,45,48,52,45,49,50,84,48,56,58,53,48,58,49,56,46,49,54,50,48,48,48,90,34,44,34,113,34,58,49,57,50,125,0]

The Zero at the end is obviously the offending value:

I am attempting to remove it with function

```
var data = msg.payload;
console.log("payload data: length = " + data.length);
data = data.trim();
console.log("trimmed data: length = " + data.length);

msg.payload = JSON.parse(data);
return msg;
```

Now am getting TypeError: data.trim is not a function

Flow looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbTai.jpg)
Now getting

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Is that payload text? It’s JSON. So… parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

By default most nodes will be outputing a JSON object already so there will be no need to parse it as a string just access the objects values directly e.g.

```
var d = msg.payload.d;
```

If the nodes are output String representations of JSON then you should use the built in JSON node to convert the string in msg.payload to a JSON object before accessing the values.

[image]

Also you need to return a whole JSON object from a function node, not just a string (or an array of strings)

So if you just want to the pass the d value on it should be:

```
var d = msg.payload.d;
msg.payload = d;
return d;
```

Comment: A little additional information:  As I am working with the suggestion.

Comment: My incoming information from MQTT is: 4/11/2018, 5:16:39 AMnode: 420b60b.46fada
GalReg/EAF_MWatts : msg.payload : buffer[61]

Comment: This includes a buffer of     [123,34,100,34,58,50,57,51,55,44,34,100,116,34,58,50,44,34,116,115,34,58,34,50,48,49,56,45,48,52,45,49,49,84,49,48,58,49,56,58,48,53,46,51,48,54,48,48,48,90,34,44,34,113,34,58,49,57,50,125,0]

Comment: My understanding is that this equates to       {"d":2937,"dt":2,"ts":"2018-04-11T10:19:44.363000Z","q":192}

Comment: I created a function of :   
var d = msg.payload.d;
msg.payload = d;
return d;

I get no debug output.

Comment: If payload is a buffer you will need to parse it to a string first, then pass it through the JSON node and then into your function node. The MQTT node should parse valid UTF8 strings automatically so we need to work out what encoding that buffer is in.

Comment: Edit the question to include a screen shot of your current flow. The payload buffer looks like the right string so should work once you've fed it through the JSON node

Comment: Also I don't think Javascript strings are normally null terminated (try removing the trailing 0 from the buffer)

Comment: Yep, the problem is the null char on the end breaking the JSON parsing. you need to trim off the last entry in the buffer

Comment: Attempted the following:
var data = msg.payload;
console.log("payload data: length = " + data.length);
data = data.trim();
console.log("trimmed data: length = " + data.length);

msg.payload = JSON.parse(data);
return msg;

Comment: Trim doesn't work to remove null (just hit this on something else. use the following `data.replace(/\0/g, '')`